# Wordpree PODS default value for image field

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, wordpress-media

Simple question, how do I configure a default fallback image for a image/video/media - custom field if no file is chosen?

I've tried adding the media url to the "default"-fields under advanced but don't seem to work, and I can't find any documentation regarding the media field in particular.

Comment: did you try entering the image ID as the default field value?